# How to Use Domain name for Elasticsearch Connection in Python

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, kubernetes-ingress

We have deployed Elasticsearch(**8.3**) using kubernetes, ingress is defined for Elasticseach as `https://elasticsearch.url.com/es`, but when I am using the same to connect to Elasticsearch using Python elasticsearch package, I am getting error below:

Note: I have tried giving port number(`https://elasticsearch.url.com:9200/es/`)but still did not worked.

**ValueError: URL must include a 'scheme', 'host', and 'port' component (ie 'https://localhost:9200')**

I am using below code to connect:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
client = Elasticsearch(
    ["https://elasticsearch.url.com/es/"],
    http_auth=('username', 'password')
)
```

Kindly help me here how to resolve this.

Comment: are you able to access elasticsearch from browser or curl using `https://elasticsearch.url.com/es` url ?

Comment: yes, I am able to query using web and curl

Answer (score 1):

the clients expect something like `https://elasticsearch.url.com:9200/`, as anything after the last `/` is considered a path/action of some sort, eg `_search` or an index name, for Elasticsearch to then do something with based on that context

you will likely need to remove the trailing `es` part of the url, then you can use [https://elasticsearch.url.com:80/`](https://elasticsearch.url.com:80/%60) (assuming ingress port 80 redirects to port 9200 for Elasticsearch)